# Plugin that resets database and deletes all content, plugins

Tags: plugins

Is there any plugin that can immediately return a site to how it looked when just installed, including removing all extra db entries, themes and plugins installed etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WordPress Reset plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-reset/) will reset your database to its default settings. This plugin doesn’t delete files, so you’ll have to manually delete themes and plugins before using this plugin.